# NHibernate 2 + Fluent Nhibernate medium trust

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, medium-trust

Will NHibernate 2 and\or Fluent Nhibernate work in a medium trust environment. If not are there any work-arounds?

Answer (score 5):

Not sure about fluent NH - I assume it should - it just translates to XML.

With NH itself you will loose bytecode optimization, all your setters/constructors will need to be public. If you need to use lazy loading you will have to have your proxies generated with build ([NH proxy generator](http://nhforge.org/wikis/proxygenerators10/default.aspx)).

Should you have some permissions enabled in your medium trust settings you can relax some of the restrictions.