# assembly does not allow partially trusted callers

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, hosting

I am building a site using fluent NHibernate, which works just fine on the dev box.
However, after I uploaded it to my host I get the following when trying to run it.

> "System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactory' threw an exception. ---> System.Security.SecurityException: That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.

Is this something I will need to resolve with the hosting company (CrystalTech)? 
Any help much appreciated.

The rest of the inner exception:

> at Castle.DynamicProxy.ModuleScope..ctor(Boolean savePhysicalAssembly, String strongAssemblyName, String strongModulePath, String weakAssemblyName, String weakModulePath) at Castle.DynamicProxy.ModuleScope..ctor(Boolean savePhysicalAssembly) at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator..ctor() at NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactory..cctor() The action that failed was: LinkDemand The Zone of the assembly that failed was: MyComputer

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Comment: The problem is not NHibermate but Castle. Check this post: http://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/2009/06/24/new-adventures-under-medium-trust/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nHibernate does not work out of the box on a [medium-trust environment](http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeffrey.palermo/archive/2005/07/05/128845.aspx) (which most shared hosts run your application under). [Lazy Loading with nHibernate Under Medium Trust](http://blechie.com/WPierce/archive/2008/02/17/Lazy-Loading-with-nHibernate-Under-Medium-Trust.aspx) describes some of the steps taken to try to get it working.

Comment: Yikes, I had no problems when I ran a previous NHibernate app using .Net 2,0 on the same hosts. As I opted to use fluent I had to use 3.5 and then the trouble began... thanks for the help.

Comment: Fortunately, the host has an option to go full trust. Thanks again